# Unknown column '0' in 'field list'?

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL query:

```
INSERT INTO ipi_messages (Message_userID, Message_fromName, Message_fromEmail, Message_subject, Message_body) VALUES(`0`, `hope`, `thisworks@gmail.com`, `i hope`, `this works`)
```

My database schema is:

[image]

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how that error is even possible. Why would MySQL try to find `0` as one of the columns? It is clearly not even in the column declaration piece of the code.

So why am I getting the error `Unknown column '0' in 'field list'`?

Comment: How about some clarity on the -1 votes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use regular quotes `'` for string values. Backquotes are used to enclose column and table names.

Comment: Thanks @rsanchez! I am now getting a new error. Question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979633/why-is-this-mysql-syntax-incorrect).

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO ipi_messages (Message_userID, Message_fromName, Message_fromEmail, Message_subject, Message_body) VALUES('0', 'hope', 'thisworks@gmail.com', 'i hope', 'this works')
```

You need to enclose the string in either single or double quotes.Instead of quotes you used ~(tilt) symbol to enclose the values to insert into the table which caused the error.Because enclosed string in ~ will be considered as the table column name.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your Message_userID is an integer field? In that case you don't need the quotes ('0' --> 0)